# When an user views all articles, see their own articles first

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

we have two models

1. article
2. user

user have many articles
i need When an user views all articles,  see their own articles first.

**my idea**

- make two query

first query return articles related to query

```
Article.where(user_id: user_id)
```

second query

```
Article.where.not(user_id: user_id)
```

and merge result

**second Idea**
get all articles and select method in ruby

but i need best way make this

- i use Ruby On Rails 6.1 and Ruby 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run one query but sort the articles with SQL depending on if they have a matching `user_id`:

```
Article.order(Arel.sql("CASE user_id WHEN #{user_id} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END"))
```

Note: `order` does not support multiple arguments and input sanitization out of the box. Use this only, when you are sure that the `user_id` contains only a valid user id, for example, be using `current_user.id` instead of `user_id`

In Rails 7 there will be a new method called [`in_order_of`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42061/files) which would allow writing the same functionality like this:

```
Article.in_order_of(:user_id, user_id)
```

Comment: appear this error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference (Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "CASE user_id WHEN 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")`

Comment: should i use `Arel.sql()`

Comment: Yes, `Arel.sql` should fix that.

Comment: @spickermann `order` does indeed support multiple arguments. e.g. `Article.order(:user_id, :title)`. If you want different directions, use a hash `Article.order(user_id: 'desc', title: 'asc')`. And you can mix an `Arel.sql()` in as one of the multiple arguments too. Suggest you sanitize with `user_id.to_i`.

Comment: @LesNightingill I am sorry when I was not clear. What I meant is that `order` does not support passing arguments for sanitization like `where`, for example like `order(CASE user_id WHEN ? THEN 0 ELSE 1 END", user.id)`. I like your suggestion to call `to_i`.

Answer (score 1):

More programmatic approach

```
articles = Article.arel_table
case_statement = Arel::Nodes::Case.new(articles[:user_id])
  .when(user_id)
  .then(0)
  .else(1)

Article.order(case_statement)
```